# Why not using curly braces with operators made with \DeclareMathOperator give problems?

Tags: math-operators, compilation-error

The following code compiles and generates the pdf properly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\zero}{\overline{0}}

\begin{document}

Writing $V_\alpha$ does not give problems.

\end{document}
```

However, the following code does give problems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\zero}{\overline{0}}

\begin{document}

Writing $V_\zero$ gives problems.

\end{document}
```

Why is that? Is there any way to make `\zero` work like `\alpha`?

Comment: Even with `\zero` defined by `\def\zero{}` (which is the way to define a macro in raw TeX), you can't write `V_\zero`. It's more `V_\alpha` which seems an exception (the standard definition of `\alpha` is `\mathchar"010B`).

Comment: @F.Pantigny You could expand that comment into an answer.

Comment: the latex syntax is _always_ to brace, precisely to avoid exposing the internal definition of each command to determine when it is possible to omit the braces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the *TeXBook*, p. 128, it's said : *Notice that ^ and _ apply only to the next single character*.

Therefore, the fact that `V_\alpha` works should probably be considered as an exception. Remark that the standard definition of `\alpha` is `\mathchar"010B`.

With a macro, defined in raw TeX by `\def`, it does not work (at least, it does not always work) since, with `\def\zero{}`, you can't write `V_\zero`.

Remark also that what follows `^` of `_` is not treated by TeX as the argument of a macro. The characters `^` and `_` are very special (as special, let's say, as `{` or `#`). The catcode of `^` is 7 and the catcode of `_` is 8 (whereas, for example, the catcode of `{` is 1, etc.). That means that you should not expect `^` and `{` to have the behaviour of a macro (even a character with catcode 13 which behaves as a macro).

Many people would probably recommend writing `V_{\alpha}` (as they recommend writing `\frac{1}{2}` instead of `\frac12` — which works...).

Answer (score 6):

While it is “almost correct” to say that TeX regards what comes after `^` or `_` like the argument to a macro, it's actually skipping a fundamental fact about them.

And this is where things go wrong with your `V_\zero`.

The fundamental difference with argument to macros is that when you have a macro taking an argument (an undelimited one, to be precise), say `\foo`, then TeX will look for the argument *without doing any expansion*: if an open brace follows, then the entire content up to the matching closing brace will be taken as the argument; otherwise the next token will be taken as the argument.

To the contrary, upon seeing `^` or `_`, TeX *will* expand tokens in order to see whether an open brace (possibly implicit) follows; in the process, `\relax` and space tokens are ignored. Such expansion process terminates as soon as an unexpandable token (other than `\relax` or a space) is found; if it is an open brace, then the argument will be grabbed up to the matching closing brace (that can be implicit as well).

Thus you can do

```
V_\bgroup 10\egroup
```

and this will take `10` as the subscript. Note that if `\foo` is a macro taking an argument, then `\foo\bgroup 10\egroup` will take `\bgroup` as the argument (probably with bad side effects).

You can test it with simple plain TeX code.

```
\def\foo#1{(#1)}
\def\x{\bgroup}
\def\void{}

\foo{10}

\foo\bgroup 10\egroup

$V_{10} = V_\bgroup 10\egroup=V_\x 10}$

$V_\void x$

\bye
```

[image]

With `\foo\bgroup 10\egroup`, the token `\bgroup` is taken as the argument so the input stream will become

```
(\bgroup)10\egroup
```

(second line). The third line shows that all those (bizarre) inputs lead to the same result.

The fourth line shows that `\void` is expanded; the expansion is empty, so TeX keeps looking for an unexpandable token (with macro expansion); it finds `x`, so it takes it as the subscript.

Why does `V_\alpha` work? Because `\alpha` is an unexpandable token. It is ***not*** defined as

```
\def\alpha{\mathchar"010B }
```

but with

```
\mathchardef\alpha="010B
```

which is *very* different. So the look up for an unexpandable token ends when `\alpha` is scanned.

If you ask LaTeX to show how your `\zero` is actually defined with `\show\zero`, you will see

```
> \zero=macro:
->\protect \zero  .
```

(there's a space in the name of the final command, but this is not important). The rules explained above have the consequence that `\zero` is expanded to `\protect\zero•` (the bullet denotes the space in the name). Since `\protect` is equivalent to `\relax`, in this context, it is ignored, so TeX expands `\zero•`.

If you do `\ShowCommand\zero` you get

```
> \zero=robust macro:
->\protect \zero  .

> \zero =\long macro:
->\qopname \newmcodes@ o{\overline {0}}.
```

so the first token remaining in the input stream is `\qopname`. Now `\ShowCommand\qopname` produces

```
> \qopname=robust macro:
->\protect \qopname  .

> \qopname =\long macro:
#1#2#3->\mathop {#1\kern \z@ \operator@font #3}\csname n#2limits@\endcsname .
```

The situation is similar: `\protect` is ignored and `\qopname•` is expanded; now the error appears, because `\mathop` is unexpandable, so it is taken to be the whole subscript, but it is illegal to do

```
V_\mathop
```

for easy to understand reasons.

Conclusion: it's OK to write something like `V_\alpha` or `V_1`, but avoid omitting braces when you're not sure. Better yet, ***always*** brace subscripts and superscripts.